# iScroll. Fix the timing for scrolling part: it is very slow at the end

Tags: javascript, iscroll

Scrolling should be with the same pace consistently. It starts ok i've used all the options and its still behaving in the same way as you can see on the example.

https://codepen.io/dalladaniel/pen/RwbOOGa here you can see the example and code. Im expecting it to behave normal to have the same pace on all the scroll from begining to end, but it starts ok and the on the end it is really slow.

```
function loaded () {
    myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', {
        scrollbars: true,
        mouseWheel: true,
        interactiveScrollbars: true,
        shrinkScrollbars: 'scale',
        fadeScrollbars: false
    });

  var scrollDuration = 80000;
var scrollDelay = 1000;

setTimeout(function() {
    myScroll.refresh();
    myScroll.scrollTo(0, myScroll.maxScrollY, scrollDuration, IScroll.utils.ease.quadratic);
}, scrollDelay);  
}

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
```